production.ERROR: View [themes.edugator.index] not found
My laravel app folder structure is as follow in localhost

source /
    ├── app/
    ├── bootstrap/
    ├── config/
    ├── database/
    ├── public_html /
          ├── assets/
          ├── themes/  <-- Themes directory
          │   │       ├── edugator/
          │   │             └── index.blade.php 
          ├── index.php/
    ├── resources/
    │   ├── lang/
    │   ├── views/
    │   │   
    ├── routes/
    ├── storage/
    ├── tests/
    └── vendor/


in  hostinger shared hosting server, as follow


public_html /
    ├── assets/
    ├── themes/  <-- Themes directory
    │   │       ├── edugator/
    │   │       │   └── index.blade.php  
    ├── index.php/
source /
    ├── app/
    ├── bootstrap/
    ├── config/
    ├── database/
    ├── resources/
    │   ├── lang/
    │   ├── views/
    │   │   
    ├── routes/
    ├── storage/
    ├── tests/
    └── vendor/


index.php is as follow
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

define('ROOT_PATH',__DIR__);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../source/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../source/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/



$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../source/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);




here is function.php for themes view

if ( ! function_exists('get_theme')) {
    function get_theme(){
        $theme_slug = get_option('current_theme', 'edugator');
        $theme_path = public_path("themes/{$theme_slug}/");
        $theme_url = asset("themes/{$theme_slug}");

        $info = [
            'name' => 'Warehouse',
            'version' => '1.0.0',
            'slug' => $theme_slug,
            'view' => "themes.{$theme_slug}.",
            'path' => $theme_path,
            'url' => $theme_url,
        ];
        return (object)$info;
    }
}


/**
 * @param null $view
 * @return string
 *
 * Return current theme directory
 */
if ( ! function_exists('theme')) {
    function theme($view = null){
        return get_theme()->view . $view;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('theme_asset')) {
    function theme_asset($path = ''){
        return get_theme()->url . '/assets/' . $path;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('theme_url')){
    function theme_url($path = ''){
        return get_theme()->url . '/' . $path;
    }
}
 



here is AppServiceProvider

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Option;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        if (file_exists(base_path('.env'))) {
            try {
                DB::connection()->getPdo();

                /**
                 * Get option and set it to config
                 */
                $options = Option::all()->pluck('option_value', 'option_key')->toArray();
                $configs = [];
                $configs['options'] = $options;

                /**
                 * Get option in some specific way
                 */
                $configs['options']['allowed_file_types_arr'] = array_filter(explode(',', array_get($options, 'allowed_file_types')));
                /**
                 * Load language file from theme
                 */
                $configs['lang_str'] = [];
                $theme_slug = array_get($options, 'current_theme');
                if ($theme_slug) {
                    $local = app()->getLocale();
                    $language_path = public_path("themes/{$theme_slug}/languages/{$local}.php");
                    if (file_exists($language_path)) {
                        $configs['lang_str'] = include_once $language_path;
                    }
                }
                $configs['app.timezone'] = array_get($options, 'default_timezone');
                $configs['app.url'] = array_get($options, 'site_url');
                $configs['app.name'] = array_get($options, 'site_title');

                $configs = apply_filters('app_configs', $configs);
                config($configs);

                /**
                 * Set dynamic configuration for third party services
                 */

                /**
                 * Set dynamic configuration for third party services
                 */
                $amazonS3Config = [
                    'filesystems.disks.s3' =>
                        [
                            'driver' => 's3',
                            'key' => get_option('amazon_key'),
                            'secret' => get_option('amazon_secret'),
                            'region' => get_option('amazon_region'),
                            'bucket' => get_option('bucket'),
                        ]
                ];

                $socialConfig['services'] = [
                    'facebook' => [
                        'client_id' => get_option('social_login.facebook.app_id'),
                        'client_secret' => get_option('social_login.facebook.app_secret'),
                        'redirect' => url('login/facebook/callback'),
                    ],
                    'google' => [
                        'client_id' => get_option('social_login.google.client_id'),
                        'client_secret' => get_option('social_login.google.client_secret'),
                        'redirect' => url('login/google/callback'),
                    ],
                    'twitter' => [
                        'client_id' => get_option('social_login.twitter.consumer_key'),
                        'client_secret' => get_option('social_login.twitter.consumer_secret'),
                        'redirect' => url('login/twitter/callback'),
                    ],
                    'linkedin' => [
                        'client_id' => get_option('social_login.linkedin.client_id'),
                        'client_secret' => get_option('social_login.linkedin.client_secret'),
                        'redirect' => url('login/linkedin/callback'),
                    ],
                ];
                config($socialConfig);
                config($amazonS3Config);

                /**
                 * Email from name
                 */

                $emailConfig = [
                    'mail.from' =>
                        [
                            'address' => get_option('email_address'),
                            'name' => get_option('site_name'),
                        ]
                ];
                config($emailConfig);

                date_default_timezone_set(array_get($options, 'default_timezone'));

                require get_theme()->path . 'functions.php';

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //
            }
        }else{
            if ( ! strpos(request()->getPathInfo(), 'installations')){
                die("<script>location.href= '".url('installations')."' </script>");
            }
        }

    }
}




the problem happen when hosted on shared hosting server, i changed folder structure according to this hosting service requirements,
My laravel view not work as in local host, it cannot find themes/edugator directory in public_html folder.
Can someone please help me to solve this problem,
the error is as follow
production.ERROR: View [themes.edugator.index] not found. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [themes.edugator.index] not found. at /home/u373829038/domains/unilearn.site/source/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)


